# pyDes decrypt "data must be a multiple of 8 bytes"

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I apoligise now, my programming habits aren't very good. I have modified the basic pyDes code from thier website:

```
import os, sys, binascii
text = input ("Text to be encrypted...")
key = input ("Key...")
sys.path.append (os.path.abspath ("").split (":") [0] + ":\\Python\\Libraries\\pyDes")
import pyDes
def toKey (string):
    b = string
    a = 0
    if len (b) > 16:
        while len (b) != 16:
            b = b [:-1]
    elif len (b) < 16:
        while len (b) != 16:
            b += b [a]
            a += 1
    return b
key = toKey (key)
data = pyDes.triple_des(key, pyDes.CBC, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=pyDes.PAD_PKCS5)
print ("Before: " + text)
encrypted = str (data.encrypt (text)) [2:-1]
print ("Encrypted: " + encrypted)
decrypted = str (data.decrypt (encrypted)) [2:-1]
print ("Decrypted: " + decrypted)
```

When I run the program, the encryption works fine, however, the decryption throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Examples\Encrypt.py", line 23, in <module>
    decrypted = str (data.decrypt (encrypted)) [2:-1]
  File "E:\Python\Libraries\pyDes\pyDes.py", line 836, in decrypt
    block = self.__key3.crypt(iv,    DECRYPT)
  File "E:\Python\Libraries\pyDes\pyDes.py", line 572, in crypt
    raise ValueError("Invalid data length, data must be a multiple of " + str(self.block_size) + " bytes\n.")
ValueError: Invalid data length, data must be a multiple of 8 bytes
```

Sorry if this is really annoying and simple :-(

Comment: If encoding / decoding issues were not allowed we could remove about 30% about the questions with regard to cryptography if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be your use of `str(...)[2:-1]` to convert a `bytes` value to a string.

Perhaps you settled on using this after trying the following code

```
encrypted = data.encrypt (text)
print ("Encrypted: " + encrypted)
```

and finding that it reports the error `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`.

One thing to note about the output of the `encrypt` and `decrypt` methods (and the inputs as well, for that matter) is that they use `bytes` objects, not strings (`str`).  What you are doing is taking the `bytes` object that comes back from a call to `data.encrypt`, converting it to a string using `str` (which isn't the right way to do this) and then attempting to decrypt your string rather than the `bytes` value you got back from `encrypt`.

What you need to be doing instead is converting the text to be encrypted into a `bytes` object, using the `encode` method of a `str`, before you pass this to `data.encrypt`.  You'll need to specify a character set to do this encoding in, such as `utf-8`.  Once you get the output back from `decrypt`,  convert it back to a string using the `decode` method of a `bytes` object.

The encrypted data, however, isn't likely to be readable in any character set.  (It's quite likely not to be well-formed UTF-8, so don't try converting it into that.)  If you want to take a look at what it looks like, perhaps the best thing to do is to use the built-in [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) function, but only use that when printing the value.

After making these changes, here's what the last few lines of your code look like:

```
charset = "utf-8"
encrypted = data.encrypt(text.encode(charset))
print ("Encrypted: " + repr(encrypted))
decrypted = data.decrypt(encrypted).decode(charset)
print ("Decrypted: " + decrypted)
```

Here's the output from a sample run:

```
Text to be encrypted...example1234
Key...5678
Before: example1234
Encrypted: b'\xf1\xed6cR9p\x18u\x1e\xf7\xcb\x98\xe40\xed'
Decrypted: example1234
```

The `\xNN` sequences within the encrypted data are how Python displays individual bytes within a `bytes` object that aren't in the ASCII range.